# search function in android for getting data in mysql

Tags: android

i want to add a search Function.I have seen the tutorial. I try to add the code but still have error.Maybe,I don't understand Adapter.
   public class orderActivity extends ListActivity{

```
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ordersList;

EditText inputsearch;
 // List view
 private ListView bb;
// Listview Adapter
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_order);  


 // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

 // getting product id (pid) from intent
    username = i.getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);

 // Hashmap for ListView

    ordersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading orders in Background Thread
    new LoadAllOrders().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String oid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText()
                    .toString();
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        orderdetailActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(KEY_ID, oid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
    });

    //the search function part!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    bb = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     inputsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputsearch);
     bb.setAdapter(adapter);


    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            orderActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}


    /**
     * getting All orders from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_orders, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Orders: ", json.toString());

            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // orders found
                // Getting Array of orders
                orders = json.getJSONArray(KEY_ORDERS);

                // looping through All Orders
                for (int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = orders.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(KEY_USERNAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new    HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_ID, id);
                    map.put(KEY_USERNAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    ordersList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no orders found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        orderActivity.class);       //  no ensure to need change
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all orders
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        orderActivity.this, ordersList,
                        R.layout.all_list, new String[] { KEY_USERNAME,
                                KEY_ID},
                        new int[] { R.id.oid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

there is the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/oid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Name Label -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

there is the other layout

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Please enter the order number:"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputsearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Search orders.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:ems="10" />
<!--  Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)   -->
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

that is my log

```
03-12 09:52:00.252: W/dalvikvm(295): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x4001d800)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at   com.example.androidhive.orderActivity$2.onTextChanged(orderActivity.java:125)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6172)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6316)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at   android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:174)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:247)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:73)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-12 09:52:00.261: E/AndroidRuntime(295):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   Method)
03-12 09:52:02.294: I/Process(295): Sending signal. PID: 295 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what is the error you have? please post you log...

Comment: sorr. now i post my log

Comment: you get a NPE somewhere here: orderActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

Comment: excuse me. what should i change in the code? it is because my standard is still low.

Comment: what are you trying with that line: orderActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

Comment: i don't know
i just try to follow the website.http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please download the project on its entirety and run it. Once it works, try breaking it apart to learn the bits and pieces. And, this is in no way using the search feature for getting data from mysql.

If you wish to implement search using mysql, you need to have your table with its data. Have a filtering method on your cursor adapter. Then on the onTextChanged() listener, you have to query your database according to what user inputted.

```
eg. select * from table where name like "s%"; // if the user has inputted s.
```