# How can i make search button functionality for the search button click?

Tags: android, search, arraylist, full-text-search, search-multiple-words

[image]When i click the search button it will search the particular data from the recyclerview. I tried Searchview Listener it won't be support for the button click search.Please Anyone Can help me to complete this!,Thankyou.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Just add an onclicklistener to the search button.

```
private OnClickListener searchListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { // do something when the button is clicked 
    } 
}; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
    // Capture search button from layout      
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_btn); 
    // Register the onClick listener with the implementation above  
    button.setOnClickListener(searchListener);  
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events)

Comment: Thankyou,Can you please help me to create search button functionality?

Answer (score 1):

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Put your search functionality here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thankyou,can you please help me to create search button functionality?

Comment: Is the list in your `RecycleView` static? or do you store the list in a database?

Comment: Stored in database

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: MySQL server,I have recycler view data in Arraylist

Comment: This might help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343767/search-function-in-android-for-getting-data-in-mysql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201700/discussion-between-surianto-and-madhuslin-ks).